# Allow file access from code, but block from browser?

Tags: .htaccess, hide, block

I have my `.htaccess` file, and I have a folder with config files in there, and they contain sensitive content, e.g. database details etc. What I would like to know is, how can I block access from a browser, but allow them to be accessed via my scripts?

I know that this can be achieved inside the PHP files themselves, but I'd rather use the `.htaccess` approach where possible.

Is this actually able to be done? I've attempted it before, but in the process of denying access to the file from the browser, it also denied access from the coding.

I have looked into this before, and some of the answers I came across suggested changing the extension to something like `.inc`, and then denying access to that. However, a couple of issues I have with that is that a) It instantly alerts anyone that can see that filename, for whatever reason, that it is a config file. Also, b) If my denial code breaks, browsers will not parse it as a PHP file, but rather an `inc` file, meaning it will print the code in the browser.

Basically, can this be done within a `.htaccess` file, or do I need to put something in the header of every config file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put these files outside of your web server's document root.

You can still access them via your server-side scripts, but this ensures no direct access to them from the outside world.

Comment: This might work, except that I have multiple sites on the same server, and I would like to keep the config files with the appropriate directory. Is there any other way? Otherwise, I'll use this method.

Comment: It's quite common to have a directory structure such that the web-accessible files are actually a sub-directory of the application's root directory.  `yourapp/htdocs` and `yourapp/conf` for example.

Comment: Sounds like a good idea, actually. I'll give it a shot and report back. Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

The conventional advice is to place such files "outside of your web server's document root".  This is all well and good, but many shared hosting offerings only give write access to your public_html directory.

I use a simple convention:  any private content (that is not URI addressable) is prefixed by an underscore or in a directory that's name is prefixed with an underscore (eg. `_private` or `_include`).  I then include this rewrite rule in my DOCROOT `.htaccess` file:

```
# if a forbidden directory or file name (starting with a . or /) 
# then raise 404 Fatal return

RewriteRule (^|/)[_.] -                                            [F]
```

Remember that you'll need to prefix with a `RewriteEngine On` and/or include this at the top of *any* `.htaccess` file with the engine enabled.

Note that the "." prefix picks up files such as `.htaccess`.

Answer (score -2):

Please use a framework, these kind of issues just doesn't need to exist. If you insist though, write a .htaccess to redirect every request to a single index.php in the root directory, which then have more logic to determine whether or not the request is for a valid file and include them, otherwise generate 404 or 403. If you need performance for static files, then use RewriteCond to exclude specific directories or file type from the index.php check.

Comment: I have no idea what was just said. Please be clearer about what you're trying to explain.

Comment: @Spiritfyre: your reply come less than a minute after my posting of the answer, you didn't even bother spending a minute to read, so not understanding it is kinda expected. What's not clear about it?

Comment: I read it three times over. What do you mean use a framework? And I would rather not have to try and filter through every single file in my directory, if can be avoided.