# .htaccess to block the files inside the folder

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a doubt in .htaccess

Here is my code :

index.php

```
Welcome Page
<img src='image/one.png'>
```

The Image should be visible in the website but it should not be access if entered the url as xxx.com/image/one.png

I am using the following .htaccess

```
Options -Indexes
ErrorDocument   403 error.php
```

I read the following question but it didn't cleared me

How can i update my .htaccess file to make it possible ?

[Allow file access from code, but block from browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11355902/allow-file-access-from-code-but-block-from-browser)

Comment: That's not going to be possible with permissions, the browser requests the image 'via code' in the same way a user typing the url would.  The only way you could potentially do this is create a one time url via a php page each time the page is generated, but that gets rid of the advantage of caching.

Comment: We can't achieve this using .htaccess ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do referrer based check to prevent direct access to images. Place this rule in your root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !localhost [NC] 
RewriteRule \.(jpe?g|gif|bmp|png)$ - [F,NC]
```

But remember that `HTTP_REFERER` can be manipulated by clients.

Comment: Will you code does not allow the the user to access the files by giving path in url ?

Comment: It should allow the the images and files to be accessed by the web request. (The images should be visible on the webpage should not accessed directly). By this code the image is not getting accessed even in the webpage

Comment: That's not correct. Read more on how `HTTP_REFERER` works. Your own page will pass a valid referrer string. Make sure you replace actual domain name in the `RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER}` above.

Comment: Actually i am using at localhost, For you understanding i am telling again.. The images should be visible within the webpage, but i should not be accessed direclty by typing localhost/xx/img/a.png or localhost/xx/img

Comment: I have understood that very first time. If using localhost your condition will be: `RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !localhost` (or see updated answer)